# Some question about git rebase onto option

Tags: git, rebase

main branch:

[image]

lark branch:

[image]

after rebase
[image]
Strange!, where is the lark_file? Well, there should be three files (init, main_file, lark_file), right?

The script to create the environment.

```
#!/bin/env bash
git init
touch init
git add -- .
git commit -am init
echo a >> main_file
git add --all
git commit -am 'main a'
echo b >> main_file
git commit -am 'main b'
echo c >> main_file
git commit -am 'main c'
echo d >> main_file
git commit -am 'main d'
echo e >> main_file
git commit -am 'main e'

git checkout HEAD~5

git checkout -B lark
echo a >> lark_file
git add --all
git commit -am 'lark a'
echo b >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark b'
echo c >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark c'
echo d >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark d'
echo e >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark e'
echo f >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark f'
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: because of rebase's rename detection, Git is applying the change to the *wrong file*.  (The `--onto` flag is not required to get this effect.  You just have to have a diff in which Git produces a false/incorrect rename.)

#### Long

First, let me modify your reproducer a bit so that everyone can use it:

```sh
$ cat repro.sh
#! /bin/sh -e
mkdir t
cd t
git init
touch init
git add -- .
git commit -am init
echo a >> main_file
git add --all
git commit -am 'main a'
echo b >> main_file
git commit -am 'main b'
git tag tag-onto
echo c >> main_file
git commit -am 'main c'
echo d >> main_file
git commit -am 'main d'
echo e >> main_file
git commit -am 'main e'

git checkout HEAD~5

git checkout -B lark
echo a >> lark_file
git add --all
git commit -am 'lark a'
echo b >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark b'
echo c >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark c'
echo d >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark d'
echo e >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark e'
echo f >> lark_file
git commit -am 'lark f'

git rebase --onto tag-onto HEAD~3
```

This has a few simple changes: it makes a temporary directory `t` and `cd`-s into it, so that we can remove the temporary directory when we're done, and so that the reproducer script itself doesn't get stuck in to the repository.  More usefully, it changes the last `git rebase` to:

```
git rebase --onto tag-onto HEAD~3
```

That is, we drop the final `HEAD`—which produces a detached HEAD pointlessly—and we use a tag, `tag-onto`, as the `--onto` target on which we're going to copy the `lark d` commit.

Running this script reproduces the issue:

```
$ ./repro.sh
[much output snipped]
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in main_file
error: could not apply 1a3193f... lark d
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 1a3193f... lark d
```

The setup here is that we're trying to cherry-pick commit `lark~2` onto commit `tag-onto` (`master~3` or `main~3` depending on your initial branch).

What we need to realize is that `git cherry-pick` is a kind of `git merge`.  It does a three-way merge, with the merge base being the parent of the commit being cherry-picked.  That means it runs two `git diff`s, from parent `lark~3` to current commit `HEAD`, and from parent `lark~3` to commit `lark~2`.  Let's look at the first of these two diffs:

```
$ git diff lark~3 HEAD
diff --git a/lark_file b/main_file
similarity index 66%
rename from lark_file
rename to main_file
index de98044..422c2b7 100644
--- a/lark_file
+++ b/main_file
@@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
 a
 b
-c
```

This says we should rename the file: it should be called `main_file` now, not `lark_file`.

The second diff of course shows what you added in commit `lark d`:

```
$ git diff lark~3 lark~2
diff --git a/lark_file b/lark_file
index de98044..d68dd40 100644
--- a/lark_file
+++ b/lark_file
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 a
 b
 c
+d
```

So Git decides that we need to rename `lark_file` to `main_file` and add `d` to the end, at the same time as removing `c` from the end of `main_file`.

That is indeed what Git has done: we now have one file `main_file` instead of two separate files `lark_file` and `main_file`, and we see the conflict.  Mine is in `diff3` style rather than `merge` style, so it has more information:

```
$ cat main_file 
a
b
<<<<<<< HEAD:main_file
||||||| parent of 1a3193f... lark d:lark_file
c
=======
c
d
>>>>>>> 1a3193f... lark d:lark_file
```

Git is behaving correctly according to the Git rules.

The fact that the Git merge rules produce surprises now and then is why you must always inspect *any* merge result.  This includes cherry-pick results, which are merge results.

Comment: Well, the cherry-pick section really confused me, I have to say I didn't follow.

Comment: A cherry-pick is a form of merge. A merge works by finding *three* commits, not two. This makes more sense for a conventional merge, where you're really merging work since a common starting point, but it's used for cherry-pick as well. Rebase is repeated cherry-picking, so each "copy a commit" step uses `git cherry-pick`. So that's where all this comes from. To understand *merging* properly, you should go to the topic of merging first.